# java thead count limit in AIX?

Tags: java, aix

By executing a simple loop create Thread java program, When I use -Xmx2048M , the thread count limit by AIX is around 900, and when I decrease that parameter to -Xmx1024M , the thread count limit increase to around 2000. And my ulimit attributes are all unlimited:
ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        unlimited
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) unlimited
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited

Anyone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: reduce the thread stack, the process probably hits the virtual memory limit. I guess the default stack size (-Xss) is 1MB,

Comment: I tried to use -Xss32K ,but result is the same like before.

Comment: you can't use so low stack, try something above 128KB

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a 32-bit JVM which has a limit of about 2.8 GB of virtual memory (after OS reserved and the JVM libraries). If each thread uses about 900 KB, using a 2 GB heap leaves virtual memory for about 900 threads. If you reduce your heap sizes to 1 GB this leaves enough virtual memory for about 2000 threads.

Try using a 64-bit JVM as I would also guess you have a 64-bit OS (32-bit OS tend to have a lower limit), or reducing the maximum stack size.

64-bit JVMs are limited to about 1 TB on most OSes and I have found you can create about 32K threads before you run into some limit (I haven't worked out what)

Here is an article I wrote on the topic for Linux http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I really using a 32-bit JVM,but I tried Xss32k or Xss8K, the result is always around 900...

Comment: That should have helped. Added a link to an article I wrote on the topic.

Comment: 8k-32k is totally unacceptable low stack value. I guess it just revers to the default 1MB then